# what's a productive environment for nodeunit?

Tags: node.js, nodeunit

I use sublime text to author node.js projects. I also use nodeunit to run tests. So far I've used its console mode, which does not generate visually appealing results. I then used the html mode, which introduces the need to switch to another window (the browser). I have too much windows...

How would you recommend to use nodeunit in the most productive way?

Answer (score 0):

For development I would never use an html reporter to run unittests. The only reason I would use a html reporter is for reporting the results to others. I checked nodeunit and there are a few reporters you can use if you don't like the default one. Worsed case scenario you can write your own reporter as is explained in the documentation.